# How do I create table if a reference record doesn't exist else insert?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I designed a system which received request with ResortId, DayId, SkierId, Time, LiftId.

I created a table called day_resort with ResortId, DayId, and a reference which equals the concatenation of ResortId and DayId. When I received a request with Reference (ResortId + DayId) exists in the day_resort. I will simply find the table with name = Reference and insert SkierId, Time, and LiftId there. On the contrary, if I don't find certain Reference in day_resort, I will create a table name after ResortId + DayId, and I will insert the record with ResortId, DayId, ResortId + DayId into day_resort, after that, I will go to the table name after ResortId + DayId and insert a record with SkierId, Time, and LiftId.

Here is the example I tried:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS createLogTable;
CREATE PROCEDURE createLogTable(tblName VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN

    SET @tableName = tblName;
    SET @sql := CASE 
        WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM day_resort WHERE Reference = @tableName) THEN
            'INSERT INTO day_resort (ResortId, DayId, Reference) VALUES ("Marriot", "21", "Marriot21")';
        ELSE 
            CONCAT('INSERT INTO `' , @tableName, '` (SkierId, TIme, LiftId) VALUES ("111", "222", "333")');
    END;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS @tableName (
        id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        SkierId VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
        Time VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        LiftId VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
END //
```

I got an error of Error Code: 2014 Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Thanks for any help

Comment: That syntax is NOT tsql, so you should remove that tag.

Comment: But why do any of this?

Comment: @Strawberry Please give me any helpful thoughts. If you don't recommend I do this, then provide me a better way. It is much helpful than saying why do any of this.

Comment: But I'd like to understand your reasoning. Why are you using a procedure to create a table?